# Longest path in ordered graph

Tags: algorithm

Let G = (V, E) be a directed graph with nodes v_1, v_2,..., v_n. We say that G is an ordered graph if it has the following properties.

- Each edge goes from a node with lower index to a node with a higher index. That is, every directed edge has the form (v_i, v_j) with i < j.
- Each node except v_n has at least one edge leaving it. That is, for every node v_i, there is at least one edge of the form (v_i, v_j).

Give an efficient algorithm that takes an ordered graph G and returns the length of the longest path that begins at v_1 and ends at v_n.

If you want to see the nice latex version: [here](http://www.cs.uiuc.edu/class/sp08/cs473/Homework/HBS/Midterm2Review.pdf)

My attempt:

Dynamic programming. Opt(i) = max {Opt(j)} + 1. for all j such such j is reachable from i.

Is there perhaps a better way to do this? I think even with memoization my algorithm will still be exponential. (this is just from an old midterm review I found online)

Comment: Doesn't matter now after more than five years since the day you asked this question, but the link in your question is broken. Additionally, this broken link doesn't impact your question or answers, so doesn't matter. Just pointing it out for future readers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your approach is right, you will have to do

```
Opt(i) = max {Opt(j)} + 1} for all j such that j is reachable from i
```

---

However, this is exponential only if you run it without memoization. With memoization, you will have the memoized optimal value for every node j, j > i, when you are on node i.

For the worst case complexity, let us assume that every two nodes that could be connected are connected. This means, `v_1` is connected with `(v_2, v_3, ... v_n)`; `v_i` is connected with `(v_(i+1), v_(i+2), ... v_n)`.

Number of Vertices (`V`) = n

Hence, number of edges (`E`) = `n*(n+1)/2 = O(V^2)`

Let us focus our attention on a vertex `v_k`. For this vertex, we have to go through the already derived optimal values of `(n-k)` nodes.

Number of ways of reaching `v_k` directly = (k-1)

Hence worst case time complexity => `sigma((k-1)*(n-k)) from k=1 to k=n`, which is a sigma of power 2 polynomical, and hence will result in `O(n^3)` Time complexity.

Simplistically, the worst case time complexity is `O(n^3) == O(V^3) == O(E) * O(V) == O(EV)`.

Answer (score 5):

Thanks to the first property, this problem can be solved O(V^2) or even better with O(E) where V is the number of vertices and E is the number of edges. Indeed, it uses the dynamic programming approach which is quiet similar with the one you gives. Let opt[i] be the length of the longest path for v_1 to v_i. Then

```
opt[i] = max(opt[j]) + 1 where j < i and we v_i and v_j is connected, 
                         using this equation, it can be solved in O(V^2).
```

Even better, we can solve this in another order.

```
int LongestPath() {
   for (int v = 1; v <= V; ++v) opt[v] = -1;
   opt[1] = 0;
   for (int v = 1; v <= V; ++v) {
     if (opt[v] >= 0) {
     /* Each edge can be visited at most once,
        thus the runtime time is bounded by |E|.
      */ 
      for_each( v' can be reached from v) 
         opt[v'] = max(opt[v]+1, opt[v']);
    }
  }
 return opt[V];
```

}

Comment: i guess the running time of the first sol. would be O(V*E), not O(V^2)